# Catching up to my foe

Tags: riddle, knowledge, chess

I had once made a piece of wonderful art
Until then it had been a century's vain of work
Spent inside those Russian winter days
At last made in the early eighties

---

But a friend of mine had recently stolen
A new, similar work that is just as golden
So outside I chased him in the night
Challenge self-made to catch him in four minutes plight

---

So I walked straight forward and came across him
He saw me, had to make a quick choice then
Four paths before in front, he had to decide
Which to take and which to leave behind

---

But I had calculated the possibilities of each
After my move, in three blocks I would always reach
And at a dead end, my friend I would catch
Give a quick punch and grab back my sketch

---

For each choice he had, I had four more to make
Only one matched one, or else my challenge to forsake
Quite poetic, I must add, of my artwork I made
In which I had delivered one man's bane

---

In the end, this is a story to be told
Although not accurate, as if plated in gold
Who am I, and what is my famous work?
Please note I refer not to its horrible predecessor
And who's bane did I deliver at last?
Explain each and every line as much as you can!

---

Hint:

> Allumwandlung

Comment: I think we deserve a hint...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be referring to

> [Leonid Yarosh's problem in Shakhmaty v SSSR, March 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babson_task#Directmate_Babsons), the first chess problem satisfying the Babson task.

That's the answer to the lines "Who am I, and what I my famous work?".

---

Other clues:

Until then it had been a century's vain of work

> The Babson task was proposed by Babson in 1884, almost a century earlier.

Spent inside those Russian winter days
At last made in the early eighties

> Yarosh was a Russian, 1983 is in the early eighties

So I walked straight forward and came across him

> Refers to the key, 1. a7 (a pawn moving forward)

Four paths before in front, he had to decide

> Black has four thematic responses, the four promotions of pawn a2

Challenge self-made to catch him in four minutes plight

> It's a mate-in-four problem.

After my move, in three blocks I would always reach

> After all Black responses, White can mate in three

For each choice he had, I had four more to make
Only one matched one, or else my challenge to forsake

> White's second move is a promotion as well, and White must promote to the same piece as Black

Please note I refer not to its horrible predecessor
And who's bane did I deliver at last?

> Pierre Drumare tried in vain for years to compose a Babson task problem, but didn't succeed; all his attempts had one or more flaws (mate in 5, illegal positions, using promoted pieces)